# Get position of each item from a sortable list with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery-ui sortable `<ul>` created with `ng-repeat`.
When I click on my submit button, I would like to get `id` of each `<li>` with their position in the list. I know there is the jquery `index()` method, but I have no idea how to write it.

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="" ng-repeat="ex in exercises">
    <div class="row zone " id="ex.id">
      <div class="zone-header"> {{ex.title_exercise}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 zone-body">
        Something
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="submit" ng-click="generate()" class="btn blue-background">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Where's the directive for the jQuery UI sortable code? You can update the scope using the events in `sortable` plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`toArray`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) and [serialize](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) methods of sortable as shown below:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.exercises = [{
      "id": "ex_1",
      "title_exercise": "one"
    }, {
      "id": "ex_2",
      "title_exercise": "two"
    }, {
      "id": "ex_3",
      "title_exercise": "three"
    }];
    $scope.generate = function() {
      console.log($scope.toArray());
      console.log($scope.serialize());
    }
  }).directive('sortable', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.sortable();
      scope.toArray = function() {
        return element.sortable("toArray");
      }
      scope.serialize = function() {
        return element.sortable("serialize",{ key: "ex" });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul id="sortable" sortable>
    <li class="" ng-repeat="ex in exercises" id="{{ex.id}}">
      <div class="zone-header">{{ex.title_exercise}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="generate()" class="btn blue-background">Generate</button>
</div>
```

Also checkout the [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) module so that you don't have to write your own sortable directive.